# Adding button on ActivityResult when using fragments Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am making an app, that will have FragmentsActivity and after clicking on Floating Action Button making a simple button on the screen. How I should implement something like that. Now I have got this:

at **main.java**

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monday_act, container, false);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rel);
            rl.addView(new DayView(this.getContext(), getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent addClass = new Intent(getActivity(), AddClass.class);
                    startActivityForResult(addClass, 1);
                }
            });
return rootView;
        }
```

and the onActivityResult:

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 1)if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                final Button lesson = new Button(this.getActivity());
                lesson.setText("Button");
                lesson.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                lesson.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                lesson.setX(100);
                lesson.setY(100);
                lesson.setWidth(100);
                lesson.setHeight(150);
                lesson.setTextSize(100);
RelativeLayout(this.getActivity());
                rl.addView(lesson);
       }

    }
```

Both functions are in `public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {`

Comment: You will need to move onActivityResult() to your FragmentActivity for the method to work. Try that and see if the button appears when you press the FAB.

Comment: I did that and it didn't work. My view is done by canvas and I want to make a button on it, before I made Fragment, on one single screen it works, but after changing to fragments it doesn't work properly. I tried in the same way add button but inonCreateView and it works, but onActivityResult I cannot do anything with fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `onActivityResult()` between `Activity` and `Fragment`

> you use it between two Activities

A `activity` will command another `activity` to do some work on some `data` passed to it or a request is made to the other activity to fetch something or do something and return the result.

after the work is done the worker Activity finishes it self and returns the result to the activity which started it.

And the activity who issues the work will have `onActivityResult()` it updated the UI depending on the result it gets

Comment: it is between two activity, the addClass activity is to fulfill some information and create a button in special manner like color and so on, and I am able to send data between Activities and Fragments, my problem is to draw a button, because I got the result of the activity in previous one and I shoulde be able to create a button, but app doesn't give me any error. Maybe it is important that DayView is a class made in Java to draw a layout as a canvas?